# How to set specific item number per silde on caroysel using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I use carousel to display items (items loaded from json) but I need 4 items to be displayed per slide and no more.This is the code to display items:

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel1" data-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
       <div class="item active">
       <ul class="thumbnails" id="output">
   </ul>
</div>
```

and this is the jQuery script to load items:

```
$(function() {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_json.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {get_param: 'value'},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        $('#output').append('<li class="caption"><div class="col-md-3"><div class="item_img"><img src="' +item.image+ '" /></div><div class="item_title">"' +item.title+ '"</div><div class="item_descr">'+ item.description +'</div></div></li>');

        });
      }
   });
});
```

this code displaying MORE than 4 items per slide but I want to show just 4.Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

change the success method like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
       if(index < 4){
          $('#output').append('<li class="caption"><div class="col-md-3"><div class="item_img"><img src="' +item.image+ '" /></div><div class="item_title">"' +item.title+ '"</div><div class="item_descr">'+ item.description +'</div></div>  </li>');
       }
    });
```

Comment: Yes I think it is right.But the fact is that I have 6 transaction in my database table.In the first slide 4 items are displayed and I want the other 2 to the next slide but the aren't displayed..

Comment: @platanas20,what plugin are you using?

Comment: I believe I want a `for..loop` instead of  `if statement` to display 4 items per slide.For example If the database table has 10 transaction then the output must be 4 items in the 1st slide > the other 4 in the 2nd slide > the last 2 in the 3rd slide.

Comment: @platanas20, yes that's for sure but I think you should create a sample like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hsh85/JS6JV/540/) on jsfiddle or plunker to address the issue properly.

Comment: I cannot figure this out!Do you have any idea how I can make this happen?